# Group and then use limit in mongoid

Tags: mongoid

I'm trying to group and then use limit and skip .
 I also  tryied to group and then paginate . But since group_by returns a hash , I am not able to do any of the two.

```
 A.where(query).group_by(&:order_id).paginate
```

OR

```
 A.where(query).group_by(&:order_id).limit().skip()
```

Let me know how I can do it.

Comment: @muistooshort - I am doing grouping since I need to show grouped data based on order_id. My problem is how can I do it .Since on Enumerable I cant do limit or skip.

Comment: @muistooshort : suppose 'A' has order id =1,amount =10 ; order id =1 ,amount=20;order id= 2, amount = 50 . The output should be order id 1 ,amount = 30  and order id 2 , amount = 50.